# Specifications for concave polygons

Tags: geometry

What makes a polygon concave or convex? We all know that convex polygons have angles less than $180^{\circ}$ and concave polygons don't, but what really makes a polygon concave? In other words, what must happen for at least one angle in the polygon to be more than $180^{\circ}$?

Comment: What must happen is that at least one angle must be more than $180^\circ$. I think I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Rahul What makes an angle more than $180^{\circ}$ in a polygon is my question.

Comment: Are you asking this from a computational point of view? (I.e. the polygon is given as an ordered circular list of pairs of coordinates, so at any vertex it is not clear which of  the two angles formed with the consecutive vertices is inside and which is outside the polygon.)

Comment: @RoryDaulton Yes, I am asking how does one tell if a polygon is concave without saying it has an angle greater than $180^{\circ}$.